# How to update multiple selected rows with a same value under a same column in listbox

Tags: vba

[image]Hi. I'm new to VBA

I have a listbox1 with multiple columns data. Every time I click on the delete button, I want it to fill .cell ( row, 8) which is under Status column to "Discarded" for each data. I've done the following code. I can multi select my rows but out of the selected rows, only one row can get its status changed.  Please help. Thank you.

```
Private Sub DeleteCartonButton_Click()

 Dim cl     As Range
 Dim rIds   As Range
 Dim Rw     As Long
 Dim String1 As String
 Dim i As Long, msg As String, Check As String

    'Generate a list of the selected items
    With ListBox1
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .Selected(i) Then
                msg = msg & .List(i) & vbNewLine



                String1 = Menu.ListBox1.List(Menu.ListBox1.ListIndex, 0)

                With Sheet1
                   Set rIds = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
                   With rIds
                       Set cl = .Find(String1, LookIn:=xlValues)
                       If Not cl Is Nothing Then Rw = cl.Row
                   End With                                   
                   .Cells(Rw, 8).Value = "Discarded"   
                End With
                UserForm_Initialize
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    If msg = vbNullString Then
        'If nothing was selected, tell user and let them try again
        MsgBox "No Carton was selected. Please make a selection."
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: what is not working? You cannot do a multiselect? Or not all selected records get their status changed?

Comment: I can multi select my rows. But only one of the selected can get its status changed

Comment: So your ListBox is referenced in a worksheet? Like `ListBox1.RowSource = "address"`? and you want to select and update status on the WS and at the same time on your ListBox at runtime? Is that your question?

Comment: Another question: Does the worksheet update but not the ListBox? Also I scanned your code and there's a floating `For Each Loop`. Can you verify if what's that for?

Comment: Hi. As for your first question is yes. And the second question for the for each loop, I have aldy removed it. It's was my failed attempt. The listbox does update with the worksheet. It's just that i want to update multiple times at one click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based from your comment try this:

```
'~~> get all the selected indexes
Dim myindex, index     

With ListBox1
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(i) Then
            If Not IsArray(myindex) Then
                myindex = Array(i)
            Else
                ReDim Preserve myindex(UBound(myindex) + 1)
                myindex(UBound(myindex)) = i
            End If
        End If
    Next
End With

If IsEmpty(myindex) Then Exit Sub '~~> if nothing is selected
'~~> update the sheet
With Sheet1
    For Each index In myindex
        .Range("H2").Offset(index,0).Value = "Discarded"
    Next
End With

'~~> update the ListBox1 display
DoEvents
Listbox1.RowSource = "'[WorkbookName]SheetName'!RangeAddress"
```

You need `DoEvents` to visually update the *ListBox*.
I'm also pointing out that you should explicitly assign the *RowSource Property*.
This will avoid errors and unexpected output.
I assumed your data starts in Cell H2, replace it otherwise.

Comment: Cool. I thought your 1st comment was just late cause you've accepted it without trying first. But anyways glad it helps. :) Although it's a good thing, you can wait a while before you accept answers. There's a possibility that a more suitable answer will come. And SO works that way, to give the best solution for specific programming issues.

Comment: Hi L42. I have got a question again. Could you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23924040/why-i-cannot-execute-a-code-in-an-autofiltered-data-list-in-vba. Thank you