# Why I cannot execute a code in an autofiltered data list in vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA. I can populate data into a listbox, perform a delete function on the data list. It works well, but once I autofiltered that data, my delete function cannot work anymore on the filtered data.

I'm trying something like this. My column of the listbox is unique ID assign to each row of data. If this unique ID is selected, it should get its corresponding ("H2").offset  = "Discarded"

```
Private Sub DeleteCartonButton_Click()

     Dim myindex, index
     Dim i As Long

        With ListBox1
            For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
                If .Selected(i) Then
                    If IsEmpty(myindex) Then
                        myindex = Array(i)
                    ElseIf IsArray(myindex) Then
                        ReDim Preserve myindex(UBound(myindex) + 1)
                        myindex(UBound(myindex)) = i
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End With

        index = Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 0)

        If IsEmpty(myindex) Then Exit Sub '~~> if nothing is selected
        '~~> update the sheet
        With Sheet1
            For Each index In myindex
                .Range("H2").Offset(index, 0).Value = "Discarded"
            Next
        End With

        '~~> update the ListBox1 display
        DoEvents
            ListBox1.RowSource = rSource.Address(external:=True)

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, your delete routine will not work on filtered data. Why? Because although you have loaded it in Listbox correctly, that does not retain or reference to it's original cell or range row. When you iterate using the Listbox index, it will not correlate with the actual number of offset you have to make to get to your target cell. For example, item "apple" is in row 5 and when you filter it, it is second on the list box. You have no way to use the Listbox index as reference to get to row 5.

Comment: I see. So how can I get the actual number of offset when I select that particular row in my filtered list? Is there any other alternate way to do it? Please advise.

Comment: If your rsource is returning the correct range, then just tweak your code in updating the sheet a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit1:**
You said Listbox1 is populated correctly.
Also, you said your ID's are unique.

So try this:

```
Dim myid As String, rtarget As Range

With Sheet1
    For Each index In myindex
        myid = Listbox1.List(index, 0)
        Set rtarget = .Range("A:A").Find(myid, [a1]) '~~> Assuming ID's in ColA
        If Not rtarget Is Nothing Then rtarget.Offset(0,7) = "Discarded"
        Set rtarget = Nothing
    Next
End With
```

Not tested so I leave it to you.

Comment: Hi. Tried but it didn't work. I was thinking of using my col A which is unique ID assigned to each row. Is there a way that I can delete where this unique ID is selected?

Comment: Let's start with filling the Listbox1. Are you able to populate your Listbox1 properly? Does it show the filtered items only?

Comment: Yes. I'm able to fill my listbox1 properly. Everything works well until I filtered my data and like you said. It is because of the index changed when data is filtered. So I add a new column A and assigned unique ID to each of the row.

Comment: I hope that selected item in the listbox will be identified by the unique ID and perform delete function as accordingly.

Comment: I managed to figure out how to delete on filtered data in a row only. I was still working on it and that when your answer came. Thank you so much again L42!